# DIY: emulate button-press on garage door remote

Tags: hardware, diy

I have a 3-button / 3-door garage door remote powered by a 3V CR2032 battery. I would like to use it in a DIY project where, by connecting it to a 3V circuit, I hope to programatically open/close the garage door.

With the battery in the remote, I've already been able to emulate a button press by appropriately closing the circuit. The circuit is closed by bringing together a positive ⊥ and negative ⊤ component on the board (polarity identified by a voltage meter). There are 6 of these (2 per door, connecting either or across works).

For the next step, I tried removing the battery and stuffing the battery compartment with copper tape to close the circuit. Then I tried closing the circuit as before, this time providing power directly (via the same battery I removed from the compartment). However, this did not work.

Is there a reason this wouldn't work? I would appreciate any advice and apologies in advance if I explained poorly; happy to follow up with additional details. Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: The adhesive on your copper tape might not be conductive.  Try soldering wires directly to a convenient exposed node.

Comment: Stuffing the battery compartment with copper tape? Why did you do that? You need to supply power to the circuit board somehow if you want it to operate. Maybe I am not understanding what you meant, but it sounds like you removed the battery then shorted the battery + and - together with copper.

Comment: The ⊥ may be positive but it is not directly connected to the battery. Most likely, it is positive because there is a weak resistor connecting it to the battery voltage. The IC on that circuit board senses the voltage. When you short ⊥ to ground, you are only pulling that input down to ground. You are not shorting the battery to ground. Most likely, ⊤ is connected directly the the battery negative terminal (and circuit board ground).

Comment: The circuit needs power, so don't remove the battery.  Solder a wire onto each end of the button, then route those wires to wherever you want the new switch to be. To push the button, short the two wires together.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the answers. Just to clarify, my goal was to "relocate" the power source from the battery compartment to my external circuit which already provides 3V. But it sounds like the circuit board may need its own power, which cannot be provided by the ⊥ and ⊤  ... so is it okay to use the circuit board, with the battery, while shorting ⊥ and ⊤ by a secondary 3V connection?

Comment: every opener i've seen has a physical switch for the garage which is more reliable and simpler than hacking apart a costly remote, which you can never have enough of...

Comment: @mkeith the question I should have asked is, how can I replace the battery with a 3V external circuit that I turn on/off programmatically to open the garage door? Thanks again for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
we see here that the `⊤` is connected to battery negative. (that little gold circle in the middle and all the other vias under the cell's negative terminal testify to this)

connecting 3V to the battery positive terminal and 0V to the `⊤` and the connecitn the `⊥` to 0V should cause the appropriate
signal to be sent.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Wow!! It _does_ make sense from the visuals ... I just don't understand how circuits work ... thank you so much!